# Is there such a thing as dual failover routers?

Tags: router, wireless, failover

Are there any routers than can failover twice? like having 3 WAN ports or 2 WAN ports + a built-in 3G modem?

Let's say like primary WAN is 100 mbps ethernet from ISP, secondary is a Cable Modem and tertiary is a 3G modem (either plugged into a 3rd WAN port or built into the router)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just need some way to "rate" your preference for the WAN ports such as administrative distance.